# Creating a queryable cached result from LINQ

Tags: .net, linq

I've got a view that's relatively small and I'd like to cache it after I fetch it from the DB. Since I only need certain rows based on userID, I'd rather not loop through my list of userIDs and query the database each time. I'd rather have the table in memory and then be able to perform linq queries against it to get the particular row I want.

```
var view = dbContext.view; //I know this line doesn't execute the query

for(int i = 0; i < userIDCount; i++)
{
    var dataRow = view.Where(v => v.userID == userIDs[i]);
}
```

Is there a way to keep view in memory and be able to use linq queries against it in the loop without hitting the DB over and over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var view = dbContext.view.ToList();
```

will cache your view, by creating an in-memory `IEnumerable`.  You can still run Linq queries against it.

However, consider putting the result in a `Dictionary`.  It will be much faster to get rows by index.

Comment: Yeah, but then I can't run LINQ queries against it.

Comment: Of course you can.  `ToList()` creates an `IEnumerable`.  All of the Linq extension methods still apply.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx

Comment: Yes... yes you can. Sorry about that. I was under the impression that LINQ only worked against IQueryable.